# Using htaccess to cloak an HTML page as a folder

Tags: .htaccess

So I have pages like:

`/features.html`

I want to link to this page as just

`/features`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ *PATH*.html
```

The text `*PATH*` should take the folder path and append `.html` to it, EXCEPT if the path ends in `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your logic, you'd arrive at:

```
RewriteEngine on
#If path ends in a forward slash, don't rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ - [L]
#If path ends in .html, don't rewrite (avoiding an infinite loop)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ - [L]
#Otherwise add .html to the end (note this will apply to images too)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But that will affect other extensions as well such as images. I'd suggest checking if the file exists or not instead like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Yes, I found straight away images/css/jss weren't loading! :-)